# SQL - How to return rows with a common column value and also based on other conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the following -

```
╔═════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ QueueID ║  AttributeName         ║ AttributeValue ║
║ 123     ║      Domain            ║  Azure         ║
║ 123     ║      Area              ║  EMEA          ║
║ 123     ║      ContractType      ║  Contract1     ║
║ 123     ║      RequestType       ║  Workshop      ║
║ 124     ║      Domain            ║  .NET          ║
║ 124     ║      Area              ║  Asia-Pacific  ║
║ 124     ║      ContractType      ║  Contract2     ║
║ 124     ║      RequestType       ║  Critical      ║
╚═════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

I want to find the QueueID for the following combination

```
Domain = .NET; Timezone = Asia-Pacific; ContractType = Contract2; RequestType = Critical
```

Basically, I'd like to find the QueueId for a specified combination, which in the example above would be 124

Comment: Are you always comparing exactly these four properties or could it sometimes be just one or two of them?

Comment: You need to learn how to use the `SELECT` statement. [This link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) is a good start. You can have a `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` statement which allows you to select based on certain condition. GL.

Comment: So, [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model) rears its ugly head once more. Does your data *need* to be in EAV form? If this data was conventionally modelled, the query would be trivial.

Comment: @JamesBlond Yes I would be comparing exactly 4 properties everytime

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I'd prefer to use EAV as the number of attributes could vary over time, so I wouldn't want to have to change the schema every single time a new attribute needs to be considered, apart from the four that's already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but please give it a try:

```
SELECT QueueID
FROM MyTable
WHERE  ( AttributeName = 'Domain' AND AttributeValue = '.NET' )
        OR ( AttributeName = 'Area' AND AttributeValue = 'Asia-Pacific' )
        OR ( AttributeName = 'ContractType' AND AttributeValue = 'Contract2' )
        OR ( AttributeName = 'RequestType' AND AttributeValue = 'Critical' ) 
GROUP BY QueueID
HAVING Count(*) = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT queueid
FROM   yourtable
WHERE AttributeName = 'Domain' AND AttributeValue = '.NET' 

intersect

SELECT queueid
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  AttributeName = 'Area'
             AND AttributeValue = 'Asia-Pacific'
intersect

SELECT queueid
FROM   yourtable
WHERE AttributeName = 'ContractType'
             AND AttributeValue = 'Contract2' 
intersect

SELECT queueid
FROM   yourtable
WHERE AttributeName = 'RequestType'
             AND AttributeValue = 'Critical'
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  ( AttributeName = 'Domain'
         AND AttributeValue = '.NET' )
        OR ( AttributeName = 'Area'
             AND AttributeValue = 'Asia-Pacific' )
        OR ( AttributeName = 'ContractType'
             AND AttributeValue = 'Contract2' )
        OR ( AttributeName = 'RequestType'
             AND AttributeValue = 'Critical' )
```

Comment: Just wondering, why you dont use `IN` clause to get various values.

Comment: @vantian That wouldn't work because the combination of the AttributeName and AttributeValue is relevant. We don't want to have the combination of 'Domain' and 'Contract2' as a valid record.

Comment: @vantian - since they're comparing multiple columns, and SQL Server doesn't yet support row value constructors for `IN`, there's no simple way to transform this without admitting false positives. E.g. *if* SQL Server supported `(AttributeName,AttributeValue) IN (('Domain','.NET'),('Area','Asia-Pacific'),...` then what you propose would work. But it doesn't.

Comment: This answer need to check count of pairs (..`HAVING COUNT(*) = 4`)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is inefficient, but compact and can handle any number of parameters in one line.

Prepare the data:

```
Declare @TestTab TABLE (
    QueueID INT,
    AttributeName VARCHAR(100),
    AttributeValue VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @TestTab
    (QueueID, AttributeName, AttributeValue)
VALUES
    (123, 'Domain'      , 'Azure'        ),
    (123, 'Area'        , 'EMEA'         ),
    (123, 'ContractType', 'Contract1'    ),
    (123, 'RequestType' , 'Workshop'     ),
    (124, 'Domain'      , '.NET'         ),
    (124, 'Area'        , 'Asia-Pacific' ),
    (124, 'ContractType', 'Contract2'    ),
    (124, 'RequestType' , 'Critical'     );

Declare @SearchString VARCHAR(MAX) = '; ' + 'Domain = .NET; Area = Asia-Pacific; ContractType = Contract2; RequestType = Critical' + ';';
```

Run the query:

```
Select QueueID
From @TestTab
Where @SearchString Like '%; ' + AttributeName + ' = ' + AttributeValue + ';%'
Group By QueueID
Having Count(Distinct AttributeName) = Len(@SearchString) - Len(Replace(@SearchString, '=', ''))
```